# Blender render doesn't upgrade

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I have been trying to figure out the reason for 2 days and have lost all hope.

The problem is that Cycles Render **doesn't upgrade**. If I make any changes in the 3D view everywhere else the changes are visible and apparent but when I try to render or animate (press buttons Render or Animate info file) under "Camera" tab, then only previous versions will be rendered.

Blender file can be located here: https://uploadfiles.io/53lbh

**What I've checked so far:**

1. I've toggled Local/Global view - no effect.
2. All viewpoints are activated in render mode (everywhere camera icon is switched on)
3. All objects have layers attached to them under RenderLayer

   4. There was no difference with either rendering in Cycles Render or Blender Render

Here is an example of the difference of both views before and after "Render" of the same frame.
[image: Here is an example of the difference of both frames]

- Is there anywhere an option that keeps only the first rendering
  result in cache and takes the information from there (that I could
  possibly need to uncheck).

HELP!

Comment: UPDATE - Right now when I try to render, the process is 20x quicker and the first 15 frames are black.

Comment: If you have anything in the VSE it will override your 3d scene. Try going to the post processing panel in the render tab of the properties panel and disable sequencer.

Comment: @Brenticus, I could kiss you right now if I knew where you lived :D I tried to kill my computer for trying to fix this issue and you managed to fix my problem in 1 minute. However now my jewel is white for some reason :P

Comment: Well, lets just say it took more than 1 minute the first time... For your jewel, what does the material look like? Is it red in the viewport and not in the render?